# xterm valid command not working in konsole nor gnome terminal

Tags: terminal, xterm, gnome-terminal, tty, konsole

this works fine with xterm

```
xterm -e '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'
```

but not with konsole nor gnome-terminal

```
konsole -e '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'  
gnome-terminal -e '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'
```

I need the parenthesis (which are the issue) because I am actually doing

```
xterm -e '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0 >/dev/tty) 2>&1'
```

both konsole and gnome-terminal say: (dialog is not recognized as a valid command.

EDIT: the following works on xterm & konsole

```
xterm -e bash -c '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'
konsole -e bash -c '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'
```

and this works on gnome-terminal

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'
```

I need to know for any existing type of terminals. if you can check it on other terminals, thanks for adding the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-e` argument is interpreted differently in these terminal emulators.

For `gnome-terminal`, you can execute

`gnome-terminal -x bash -c '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'`

Comment: it works. thanks. I've found this one: konsole -e bash -c '(dialog --msgbox "thebigmessage" 0 0)'

Comment: Haha, thanks! I noticed konsole didn't have a -x, but didn't realize its -e was just fine.

Comment: Another note: There's a `gnome-terminal.wrapper` shipped by Ubuntu, which serves the purpose that it recognizes the same flags as xterm and konsole, that is: `gnome-terminal.wrapper -e bash -c ...`